# Error: intentando conseguir la propiedad de ningun objeto en php

Tags: php

Hola estoy obteniendo un error muy seguido en php el error es:

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\login.php on line 20
```

El php es el siguiente:

```
<?php
require 'inc/base.php';

if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
  header("Location: index.php"); exit;
}

include 'inc/header.php';
?>
        <section>
            <h1 class="title"> now</h1>
                <?php
        $query = $db->prepare("SELECT timestamp FROM users WHERE id=?");
        $query->execute([$_SESSION['user_id']]);
        $data = $query->fetch();

                if ($data->timestamp == 0) {
                    echo "<div class=message_erreur></div>";
                } elseif (time() - $data->timestamp > 1296000) {
            // 15 jours
                    echo "<div class=message_erreur>Your right to use . Please buy again.</div>";
                } else {

                }
          ?>
                  <div class="message_erreur"></div>
          <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            Select file to upload:
            <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100485760" />
            <input name="filexls" type="file">
            <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit">
          </form>
          <?php
                }
                ?>
        </section>
<?php
include 'inc/footer.php';
```

Mi usuario tendría los siguientes valores:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Cuál es la línea 20? Haz un `var_dump($data);` para verificar lo que hay en los resultados.

Comment: me devuelve esto: array(2) { ["timestamp"]=> string(1) "0" [0]=> string(1) "0" }

Comment: En vez de esto: `$data = $query->fetch();`, tienes que leerlo así: `while ($data = $query->fetch(PDO::PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { if ($data["timestamp"] == 0) {
                    echo "<div class=message_erreur></div>";
                } elseif (time() - $data["timestamp"] > 1296000) {
            // 15 jours
                    echo "<div class=message_erreur>Your right to use . Please buy again.</div>";
                } else {

                } }`

Comment: me da este error cuando hago eso `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '::' (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM) in C:\xampp\htdocs\encry.php` on line 18 la linea 18 es el white()

Comment: Oh sí, me equivoqué aquí: `fetch(PDO::PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))`, debe ser: `fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))`, o sea, esto `PDO::` una sola vez, yo lo pues dos veces.

Comment: me  da error a partir de usar la linea me devuelve Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\encry.php on line 42

Comment: Revisa la respuesta que acabo de escribir. Ya que estás seleccionando solamente la columna `timestamp` y esperas un solo valor (supongo), el bucle `while` no es necesario. Pon el código como te escribí en la respuesta y prueba. Ese error debe ser debido a alguna `}` de más o de menos o algo así.

Comment: Por defecto PDO asume que la respuesta tiene el parámetro PDO::FETCH_BOTH, de manera que en vez de `$data->timestamp` debiese ser `$data['timestamp']`

Answer (score 0):

Dado que estás obteniendo una sola columna en:

```
SELECT timestamp FROM users WHERE id=?
```

entonces lo mejor **para este caso**, sería usar el método `fetchColumn()`, el cual:

> Devuelve una única columna de la siguiente fila de un conjunto de
>   resultados.
>
> <sub>[Manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php)</sub>

```
            <?php
    $query = $db->prepare("SELECT timestamp FROM users WHERE id=?");
    $query->execute([$_SESSION['user_id']]);
    $data = $query->fetchColumn(); //$data tendrá el valor de la columna del SELECT

            if ($data === 0) {
                echo "<div class=message_erreur></div>";
            } elseif (time() - $data > 1296000) {
        // 15 jours
                echo "<div class=message_erreur>Your right to use . Please buy again.</div>";
            } else {

            }
      ?>
```

> **NOTA MUY IMPORTANTE:** Verás que puse esta línea `if ($data === 0) {` con tres signos de `===`. Eso es para que te de verdadero solamente
>   si data es igual al `0` y es del mismo tipo (entero). ¿Por qué eso?
>   Porque si `fetchColumn` falla devolverá `FALSE` y la comparación `if
>   (FALSE==0) { ...`  se cumpliría, dándote entonces un falso positivo.